# Restrict parent type to multiple children

Tags: typescript

I have a parent object with type that looks something like this:

```
type ParentType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  lorem: string;
  ipsum: string;
  other: number;
}
```

Now I have another component that uses separately `foo`, `bar` and `lorem`, `ipsum` with types:

```
type FooBar = {
   foo: string;
   bar: string
}
type LoremIpsum = {
   lorem: string;
   ipsum: string;
}
```

Is there some way to provide type safety such that the parent type uses the types `FooBar` and `LoremIpsum` instead of manually defining the parent type? Using the parent type to construct the child type also works but unsure how to restrict it to specific keys of the parent. Using intersections works but how about if the parent has some other property not included in `FooBar` and `LoremIpsum` types?

Is it good to just define the `OtherType` even if its not used in any component by itself?

```
type OtherType = { other: number }
type Parent = Foobar & LoremIpsum & OtherType
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#intersections? Or https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys for the other way.

Comment: You mean `type ParentType = FooBar & LoremIpsum`?

Comment: To construct child type fron parent use `Pick` Utility type. For example `type FooBar = Pick<ParentType, 'foo' | 'bar'>
`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the parent type from the other two (It's called [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#intersections)). For example:

```js
type FooBar = {
   foo: string;
   bar: string
}
type LoremIpsum = {
   lorem: string;
   ipsum: string;
}
```

If you now do this:

```
type ParentType = FooBar & LoremIpsum;
```

The type `ParentType` will have both the properties from `FooBar` and `LoremIpsum` types.

If you want to do it the other way, you can create the children types like this (with [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility):

```js
type FooBar = Pick<ParentType, 'foo' | 'bar'>
```

And `FooBar` will be a type you create from `ParentType` and you take only the properties 'foo' and 'bar' from it.